# Why does this MOSFET not switch 9 V?

Tags: mosfet, logic-level

I am designing a circuit so that I can mute/unmute a microphone using an Arduino/Raspberry Pi.

I am using a [CD4051](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf?ts=1664670306358) which is designed for controlling audio applications.
The schematic is [based off of this blog](https://thetuberoaster.wordpress.com/2020/09/25/cd4052-audio-signal-switch/).

I am using a [dual rail power supply](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256803012424581.html?spm=a2g0o.new_account_index&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa&_randl_shipto=US) with +9 and -9 V on the CD4051.

**CD4051**
pin 16 = +9 V
pin 7 = -9 V
pin 11 = audio select (low 0 V = active, high 9 V = inactive)

[image]

Because the Raspberry Pi GPIO pins use 3.3 V, but the CD4051 uses 9 V, I am attempting to use a IRLZ34N N-channel MOSFET as a logic-level converter.

### Problem

This logic level circuit *should* allow a 3.3 V microcontroller to toggle a 9/0 V on the CD4051 (pin 11).

Yet when I prototype this circuit, I measure 3.3 V at pin `mic_A` (and pin 2 of the MOSFET). I've double checked my circuit, and even compared to [this blog article](https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/bi-directional-logic-level-controller-using-mosfet).

[image]

This is how the circuit performs in the simulator
[image] (I am using 5 kΩ resistors instead of 10 kΩ, and using an IRLZ34N instead of a BS170)

What is wrong with this logic-level converter? Why am I not getting 9 V at pin `mic_A`?

- https://thetuberoaster.wordpress.com/2020/09/25/cd4052-audio-signal-switch/
- https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/bi-directional-logic-level-controller-using-mosfet

---

### Update

> Why use an IRLZ34N?

Because thats the only TTL N-channel MOSFET I currently have.

Here is a photo of the prototype:

[image]

### Update 2

After further experimentation, I was able to get this working and have the IRLZ34N to be switched with 3.3v logic.

However based on the comments, I have also learned

1. BS170 is a better suited mosfet for this application since the IRLZ34N is intend for high current
2. +9V/-9V is not required for the CD4051
3. Logic Level Conversion is not necessary since the CD4051 logic can be controlled with 3.3v
4. I should add bypass capacitors to the power rails of the CD4051

Video of working circuit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zxkHmgybTc

Comment: Use a bs170, not a irlz34. Two very different components. The cd4051 was not designed for audio applications - it just happens that being an analog switch will switch analog audio signals. There are better devices specifically for audio.

Comment: Both the BS170 and IRLZ34 are TTL N-Channel Mosfets. While they do have different maximum continuous drain current, the specs seem similar enough that they should work in this application no? Please educate me what is different that makes the one work but the other doesn't.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload a picture of your wiring? Out of curiosity, why are you using a high-power MOSFET for switching a logical input?

Comment: @DanielMelendrez Yes. I've uploaded a photo. Regarding the choice of mosfet, it is the only TTL N-Channel that I currently have. (I assumed it would work).

Comment: It looks like it should work. But the CD4051B will work with 3V logic input, so you don't really need the level shifter. It would be good to add bypass capacitors on the power supply rails of the IC, especially if you want to switch quickly.

Comment: @PStechPaul The [datasheet section 8.1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf?ts=1664751366311&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) says `if VDD = +4.5 V,
VSS = 0 V, and VEE = –13.5 V, analog signals from –13.5 V to +4.5 V can be controlled by digital inputs of 0 V to
5 V.` Does this mean I need 5v logic?

Comment: Section 8.3 states "Logic-level conversion for digital addressing signals of 3 V to 20 V (VDD – VSS = 3 V to 20 V) to switch analog signals to 20 VP-P (VDD – VEE = 20 V). Binary address decoding on chip makes channel selection easy. When channels are changed, a break-before-make system eliminates channel overlap" So you may need to use the 3.3V supply for Vdd.

Comment: Please measure the voltage on either side of the RH 10K resistor with control input 3.3V. Your breadboard looks a bit dodgy.

Comment: What voltage will you be switching? It looks like peak voltage is just below Vdd, so if microphones work on a lower P-P voltage, you might not need +/- 9V.

Comment: The left hand yelloe wire looks like it goes to gnd on the esp32 module. Have you got the pinout of the mosfet correct?  GSD is the sequence methinks. Check the obvious.

Comment: @PStechPaul You are right. I removed 9v and got this working on 5v only. Headphones I'm using are the ubiquitous iphone style earbuds, which should have a peak-peak of <3v. 
I replaced the 3.3v microcontroller with a 5v one and the IRLZ34N is now switching like I expect. (I know I've used 3.3 MC with that mosfet in the past). Without the 9v power the need for Logic Level conversion is moot. Video of circuit https://youtu.be/C-OuItKyJpg

Answer (score 1):

Checking the datasheets from both MOSFETS (BS170 vs IRLZ34) I see three main differences:

1. Their \$t_{on}\$ and \$t_{off}\$ times, where the BS170 turns on in 10 ns (MAX). The IRLZ34 indicates a rise time \$t_r\$ of 100 ns (the datasheet does not indicate a specific \$t_{on}\$ rather a \$t_{d(on)}\$ or *turn-on delay* time of 8.9 ns (Typical))

[image: BS170 schematic timings]

2. Their input capacitances. For the BS170, \$C_{in}\$  is 40 pF (MAX) while \$C_{in}\$ for the IRLZ34 is significantly higher at 880pF (Typical). Proving a slower response time from the latter.
3. In terms of the \$R_{DS(on)}\$, the IRLZ34 outperforms the BS170, however, the test conditions and application scenario are abysmally different (low-voltage, low-current switching vs high-current switching).

These criteria are the ones proposed by Nexperia on its application note [AN97055](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf) for \$I^2C\$ Bi-directional level shifters:

[image: Nexperia on MOSFET requirements for I2C shifters]

Finally, [this guide](https://www.taiwansemi.com/assets/uploads/productcategoryfile/AN-1001_A1611.pdf) on MOSFETS parameters might help you to clarify all of these numbers.

The bottom line is: each type of transistor has its own application case.

Comment: I think the signal is very low speed.  The IRLZ34 should work,  \$V_{gs(th)}\$ is max 2 V and it has much more than enough transconductance to switch signals at a measly 3.3 V gs.

Comment: @OskarSkog that is correct, however, the higher input capacitance value might be preventing the MOSFET from fully turning on and/or for the CD4051 to register the logic level change. From personal experience, changing the type of component can make the whole difference. While these are similar technologies, their use case is different. Happened to me once using drop-in replacements from 2 Instrumentation Amplifiers on the same circuit obtaining completely different results simply due to their individual characteristics. Both chips were fully functional when testing them separately.